# How To Lock Code With password in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I Want To Add a Password System To My Code To Prevent My Code From Being Run By Someone else, is There Any Way How Can i do so?
Interface can be like asking for password before starting development server in reactjs

Comment: Could you be more precise? what is your final goal?

Comment: lock my code like if somebody runs the code he/she is required to fill a password if incorrect process will stop.

Comment: You could encrypt your code using something like CryptoJS, then prompt the user for a password and execute the eval function with the decrypted result.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together an example of what I meant in the comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SourceCode Encryption example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sjcl/1.0.8/sjcl.min.js" integrity="sha512-s0r9TyYSs5CusSDL5s/QEZQZ4DNYLDXx0S+imS+SHR9mw0Yd0Z5KNS9dw7levSp7GpjOZu/bndds3FEDrKd8dg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Hide this part from the end user
    var password = "MySourceCodePassword";
    var sourceCode = 'alert(\'Ur name is: \' + prompt("What is ur name?"))';
    var encryptedSourceCode = sjcl.encrypt(password, sourceCode);

    // User endpoint code
    // You would have the encryptedSourceCode stored into an string and only
    // is the propper key is used then it would be decrypted and evaluated.
    try {
      var userPassword = prompt("Whats the sourceCode password?");
      eval(sjcl.decrypt(userPassword, encryptedSourceCode));
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your case you would have to provide your encoded Reactjs code and the required html dom element, I have simplied this example wrapping it in an html page and prompting the user for a password but u could use a form or whatever you might require.

Be aware that once the know the key to decrypt the will be able to see your javascript source code, and so far it is the way it works, since the browser need to read javascript you cannot hide it from it. If you wanna make it harded you can always minify so it is harder to read.

Comment: This Asks For The Password at Web. Not in Terminal :(

Comment: use https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/ to do it on the terminal. This is just an example so you can have an idea, if you want precise solutions you need to provide a precise problem.